# RDP Crashes After Entering Password

Tags: rdp, windows-10

Recently I've been trying to login to various machines via RDP and am getting the following error my Windows 10 workstation:

```
Faulting application name: mstsc.exe, version: 10.0.10586.0, time stamp: 0x5632d1d8
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.10586.103, time stamp: 0x56a8483f
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x00000000000ee71c
Faulting process id: 0x3eac
Faulting application start time: 0x01d16d6d340f9399
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\mstsc.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
```

After debugging with VS 2015 it seems like a heap corruption issue.

Comment: I had/have "CSR Harmony Wireless Software Stack" version 2.1.63.0 installed.  I believe that all versions of Windows (Vista and higher) are susceptible to being messed up by this thing.  I had this issue on Windows 7 Pro.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem was from the recent CSR harmony bluetooth driver I installed. The drivers try to add some bluetooth tag authentication which was causing the issue and RDP crashes regardless of a good or bad password.

The simple fix is to head to

```
C:\Program Files\CSR\CSR Harmony Wireless Software Stack
```

and change

```
BLEtokenCredentialProvider.dll
```

to

```
BLEtokenCredentialProvider.dll.BAK
```

And the issue is now fixed for me.

Comment: I was only able to tell that the faulting module was named BLEtokenCredentialProvider.dll by using Visual Studio to debug the mstsc process post-mortem.  Unless this module was disabled, it was also being loaded into winlogon/logonui as part of the main windows login - scary stuff.

Comment: Another way to disable the BLEtokenCredentialProvider credential provider is to use [AutoRuns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx).  Go to the Winlogon tab, and uncheck the BLEtokenCredentialProvider item.

Comment: Thank you! You have no idea how much time you just saved me.

Comment: i was skeptical reading this but wow, it did fix it.  amazing the randomness of the issues.  rdp was working fine under certain accounts/computers but not under new ones.

Answer (score 12):

I had the exact same problem for months and Mike Averto's answer did the trick (thanks !).

To make it a bit less hackish, I disabled the credential provider in the registry rather than renaming the DLL:

- launch regedit.exe
- go to the key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers
- locate the subkey referring to BLEtokenCredentialProvider (5355DA8C-FE32-49b4-A567-A67535C86592 in my case)
- add to it a new DWORD32 value with name "Disabled" and value 1

Comment: Worked a treat. Just ensure that you end the task for the remote desktop before attempting to login again. My experience was that the login credentials screen kept returning and I couldn't even close that window. It always came back.

Comment: Worked for me too. What a nasty obscure error.

Comment: Renaming dll and regedit creation of BLEtokenCredentialProvider and setting DWORD32 to 1 work for me as well (also was @ 5355DA8C-FE32-49b4-A567-A67535C86592)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the DLL mentioned as well as the related registry key but I found out the culprit which is the FaceCredentialProvider by trial and error.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers\{8AF662BF-65A0-4D0A-A540-A338A999D36F}.

Comment: Please explain better how to solve

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm the FaceCredentialProvider is the problem here.

In The registry go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers\{8AF662BF-65A0-4D0A-A540-A338A999D36F}`

There you must add a REG_DWORD named "Disabled" with value "1". Or do so by running this with administrative priviledges:

```
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers\{8AF662BF-65A0-4D0A-A540-A338A999D36F}" /v Disabled /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

Answer (score 1):

My fix was similar - I had to disable

`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers\{1b283861-754f-4022-ad47-a5eaaa618894}`

Answer (score 0):

Another two penn'orth in case it helps anybody.  I've just been hit by the same problem on a Win 8 machine.  I'd just installed node js, but not wanting to believe this was the problem, I went through SFC & CHKDSK to try & fix it, to no avail.

Once I uninstalled node js, I could successfully RDP to the servers again - not sure how I'm going to be able to work on the project that needs node js though!